# Orange widgets between 2.7 and 3.2

Tags: orange

I'm running Orange 3.2 and 2.7, but both are missing key widgets for my work. 
My installation of 2.7 came without the 'Discretize' (although I've had it included before). So I moved on to 3.2, which now appears not to have the 'Regression trees' which I also use. 
Anyone else experienced this? 
Any tips? 
Can I copy widgets from one generation to another?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Orange 2.7 vs Orange 3.2 are based on two different major Python versions (2.7 and 3+) and are thus largely incompatible out-of-the-box. Not all Orange2 widgets appear to have been ported to the new version yet. Discretize missing for you in Orange2, however, appears to be a bug, which you should report on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/biolab/orange/issues).

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Orange? Which operating system do you use?

If you are on Windows, I would guess that you probably manually installed some libraries (before or after installing Orange) whose versions are incompatible with Orange. In particular, the discretization widget uses Qwt and also Orange's custom extensions of some Qt classes, written in C++. You are probably also missing most visualization widgets.

Os X does not have this problem since Python is included in a bundle.

Can you run Orange from command line with arguments `-l 4 --force-discovery` and report what it says about the discretization widget?